# CodeWars - Three-pass compiler for arithmetic expressions

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell, math-expression-eval, compiler, parsec

I'm looking for feedback on my solution to the [Tiny Three-Pass Compiler](http://www.codewars.com/kata/tiny-three-pass-compiler/train/haskell) kata on CodeWars. The kata is to implement a compiler for an arithmetic language in three passes - parsing to an AST, constant folding, then generating code in a small assembly language.

I'm looking for general stylistic review, as well as reducing some of the duplication in the `pass2` and `pass3` functions; I have a feeling that the `Add`/`Sub`/`Mul`/`Div` cases could probably be condensed somehow.

Without further ado, the code:

```
module TinyThreePassCompiler where

import Data.Map.Strict (Map)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Text.Parsec
import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as Tok

-- count number of arguments declared, how identifiers map to argument numbers
type CompilerState = (Int, Map String Int) 
type Parser a = Parsec String CompilerState a

langDef :: Tok.LanguageDef CompilerState
langDef = Tok.LanguageDef
  { Tok.commentStart    = ""
  , Tok.commentEnd      = ""
  , Tok.commentLine     = ""
  , Tok.nestedComments  = False
  , Tok.identStart      = letter
  , Tok.identLetter     = letter
  , Tok.opStart         = oneOf "+-*/"
  , Tok.opLetter        = oneOf "+-*/"
  , Tok.reservedNames   = []
  , Tok.reservedOpNames = []
  , Tok.caseSensitive   = True
  }

lexer :: Tok.TokenParser CompilerState
lexer = Tok.makeTokenParser langDef

parens :: Parser a -> Parser a
parens = Tok.parens lexer

brackets :: Parser a -> Parser a
brackets = Tok.brackets lexer

identifier :: Parser String
identifier = Tok.identifier lexer

reservedOp :: String -> Parser ()
reservedOp = Tok.reservedOp lexer

integer :: Parser Integer
integer = Tok.integer lexer

data AST = Imm Int
         | Arg Int
         | Add AST AST
         | Sub AST AST
         | Mul AST AST
         | Div AST AST
         deriving (Eq, Show)

function :: Parser AST
function = do
  brackets argList
  expression

argList :: Parser ()
argList = do
  many variableDec
  return ()

-- for each variable declaration, we add a mapping from the argument name to the argument number
-- as well as incrementing the Int in CompilerState, which tracks what argument number we're on
variableDec :: Parser ()
variableDec = do
  varName <- identifier
  (varNum, _) <- getState
  modifyState (\(num, args) -> (num + 1, Map.insert varName varNum args))
  return ()

expression :: Parser AST
expression = term `chainl1` addSubOp

addSubOp :: Parser (AST -> AST -> AST)
addSubOp =  (reservedOp "+" >> return Add)
        <|> (reservedOp "-" >> return Sub)

term :: Parser AST
term = factor `chainl1` multDivOp

multDivOp :: Parser (AST -> AST -> AST)
multDivOp =  (reservedOp "*" >> return Mul)
         <|> (reservedOp "/" >> return Div)

factor :: Parser AST
factor =  number
      <|> variableUse
      <|> parens expression

number :: Parser AST
number = do
  num <- integer
  return $ Imm $ fromIntegral num

-- using fromJust because we don't care about error handling
-- per problem, all programs will be valid
variableUse :: Parser AST
variableUse = do
  varName <- identifier
  (_, varMap) <- getState
  return $ Arg $ fromJust $ Map.lookup varName varMap

compile :: String -> [String]
compile = pass3 . pass2 . pass1

-- parsing pass
pass1 :: String -> AST
pass1 str = case (runParser function (0, Map.empty) "" str) of
  (Left _) -> error "Parse error"
  (Right ast) -> ast

-- constant folding pass
-- do a postorder traversal of the AST, checking for optimization opportunities at each node
pass2 :: AST -> AST
pass2 ast = case ast of
  Add left right -> case (pass2 left, pass2 right) of
    ((Imm m), (Imm n)) -> Imm (m + n)
    (l, r) -> Add l r
  Sub left right -> case (pass2 left, pass2 right) of
    ((Imm m), (Imm n)) -> Imm (m - n)
    (l, r) -> Sub l r
  Mul left right -> case (pass2 left, pass2 right) of
    ((Imm m), (Imm n)) -> Imm (m * n)
    (l, r) -> Mul l r
  Div left right -> case (pass2 left, pass2 right) of
    ((Imm m), (Imm n)) -> Imm (m `div` n)
    (l, r) -> Div l r
  _ -> ast

-- code generation pass
-- postorder traversal of the AST, generating code at each node
pass3 :: AST -> [String]
pass3 ast = case ast of
  Imm n -> ["IM " ++ show n, "PU"]
  Arg a -> ["AR " ++ show a, "PU"]
  Add l r -> pass3 l ++ pass3 r ++ ["PO", "SW", "PO", "AD", "PU"]
  Sub l r -> pass3 l ++ pass3 r ++ ["PO", "SW", "PO", "SU", "PU"]
  Mul l r -> pass3 l ++ pass3 r ++ ["PO", "SW", "PO", "MU", "PU"]
  Div l r -> pass3 l ++ pass3 r ++ ["PO", "SW", "PO", "DI", "PU"]
```

A few notes:

- the `AST` data type and types for `compile`, `pass1`, `pass2`, and `pass3` are set by the kata. I'm stuck with using `Int` as the underlying type for the `Imm` and `Arg` constructors.
- Everything is one module for running on CodeWars. I'd probably split this into multiple modules if it weren't for that restriction.
- Parsec is available on CodeWars; Megaparsec isn't, else I'd consider using that.
- Per the kata's description, all test programs will be valid; thus, I don't put any effort into error handling, and I'm ok with `variableUse` throwing an error if an undeclared argument is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh. I never got to solve that kata, so congratulations first.

## Working with a given AST

As you said yourself, the AST type isn't optimal. We could use

```
data AST = Imm Int
         | Arg Int
         | BinOp BinOp AST AST
         deriving (Eq, Show)

data BinOp = Add | Mul | Sub | Div deriving (Eq, Show)
```

instead and simplify both `pass2` and `pass3` a lot. The operator parsers would return a `BinOp` instead of an `AST -> AST -> AST`. But we're stuck with the current `AST`.

### Reducing code duplication (DRY)

If we have a look at `pass2` we see that all cases are *very* similar. They all follow the

```
 Constructor left right -> case (pass2 left, pass2 right) of
                             (Imm m, Imm n) -> Imm (m <op> n)
```

pattern. We can just use that one, too:

```
pass2 :: AST -> AST
pass2 ast = case ast of
  Add left right -> simplify Add (+) left right
  Sub left right -> simplify Sub (-) left right
  Mul left right -> simplify Mul (*) left right
  Div left right -> simplify Div div left right
  _ -> ast
 where
  simplify c op l r = case (pass2 l, pass2 r) of 
     (Imm m, Imm n) -> Imm (m `op` n)
     _              -> c l r
```

This variant is easier to maintain, as we only have to change `simplify` or add the new constructor to the outer `case`, e.g.

```
pass2 :: AST -> AST
pass2 ast = case ast of
  Add left right -> simplify Add (+) left right
  Sub left right -> simplify Sub (-) left right
  Mul left right -> simplify Mul (*) left right
  Div left right -> simplify Div div left right
  Pow left right -> simplify Pow (^) left right
  _ -> ast
 where
  simplify c op l r = case (pass2 l, pass2 r) of 
     (Imm m, Imm n) -> Imm (m `op` n)
     _              -> c l r
```

It's similar for `pass3`:

```
pass3 :: AST -> [String]
pass3 ast = case ast of
  Imm n -> ["IM " ++ show n, "PU"]
  Arg a -> ["AR " ++ show a, "PU"]
  Add l r -> generate "AD" l r
  Sub l r -> generate "SU" l r
  Mul l r -> generate "MU" l r
  Div l r -> generate "DI" l r
 where
  generate oc l r = pass3 l ++ pass3 r ++ ["PO", "SW", "PO", oc, "PU"]
```

This keeps the repetition in our code a little bit down.

### An intermediate representation

But we can do better if we introduce additional functions and types:

```
data BinOp = BAdd | BSub | BMul | BDiv deriving (Eq, Show)

data BinOpExpr = BinOpExpr BinOp AST AST

toBinOpExpr :: AST -> Maybe BinOpExpr
toBinOpExpr ast = case ast of
  Add l r -> gen BAdd l r
  Sub l r -> gen BSub l r
  Mul l r -> gen BMul l r
  Div l r -> gen BDiv l r
  _       -> Nothing
 where
  gen c l r = Just $ BinOpExpr c l r
```

If we now have `toOpCode :: BinOp -> String`, it's really easy to write `pass3`:

```
pass3 :: AST -> [String]
pass3 ast = case ast of
  Imm n -> ["IM " ++ show n, "PU"]
  Arg a -> ["AR " ++ show a, "PU"]
  o     -> case toBinOpExpr o of 
    Just (BinOpExpr op l r) -> pass3 l ++ pass3 r ++ ["PO", "SW", "PO", toOpCode op, "PU"]
    Nothing -> error "Unreachable"
```

Similar for `pass2` if we have `toFunc :: BinOp -> (Int -> Int -> Int)`:

```
pass2 :: AST -> AST
pass2 ast = case toBinOpExpr ast of
  Just (BinOpExpr op l r) -> simplify op l r ast
  _                       -> ast 
 where
  simplify op l r ast = case (pass2 l, pass2 r) of 
     (Imm m, Imm n) -> Imm (toFunc op m n)
     _              -> ast
```

## Other remarks

Your `Parser` are well done, but we can get rid of some superfluous code. For example

```
argList :: Parser ()
argList = do
  many variableDec
  return ()
```

can be written as

```
argList = skipMany variableDec
```

`skipMany` still *applies* the parser (and therefore changes the state), whereas `many` applies the parser and collects a list of `[()]`.

Similarly, we can get rid of `return ()` in

```
variableDec :: Parser ()
variableDec = do
  varName <- identifier
  (varNum, _) <- getState
  modifyState (\(num, args) -> (num + 1, Map.insert varName varNum args))
  return ()
```

as `modifyState f >> return ()` is the same as `modifyState f` due to the monad laws:

For `number`, we can use `Parser`'s `Functor` instance to make it shorter:

```
number :: Parser AST
number = Imm . fromIntegral <$> integer
```

The other functions *could* get written in a point-free style, but that would be harder to read in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks! These are some interesting suggestions; I'll definitely keep them in mind for future work in this vein.

Comment: @DylanSp Finally got to comment the `Parser` section. Have fun on CW!

Answer (score 0):

`Control.Lens.Plated` specializes in passes over recursive data structures.

```
pass2 = rewriteOf uniplate $ fmap Imm . \case
  Add (Imm left) (Imm right) -> Just $ left + right
  Sub (Imm left) (Imm right) -> Just $ left - right
  Mul (Imm left) (Imm right) -> Just $ left * right
  Div (Imm left) (Imm right) -> Just $ left / right
  _ -> Nothing
```

`Control.Lens.Prism` specializes in abstracting over constructors.

```
pass2 = rewriteOf uniplate $ \ast -> listToMaybe
  [ Imm $ f left right
  | (p, f) <- [(_Add, (+)), (_Sub, (-)), (_Mul, (*)), (_Div, (/))]
  , Just (Imm left, Imm right) <- pure $ preview p ast
  ]
```